# is storing data using file input/output stream method secure

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

if i use the file input/output stream method, will the data that is stored in the application be secure even if it is basic security, for example does it make it more difficult for unauthorised access to that data? this is the class for the data storage.

```
public class Utilities {

public static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".bin";

public static boolean saveNote(Context context, Notes notes){
    String fileName = String.valueOf(notes.getDateTime()) + FILE_EXTENSION;

    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    try {

        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(notes);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false; //tell the user something went wrong
    }

    return true;
}

public static ArrayList<Notes> getSavedNotes(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Notes> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
    filesDir.getAbsolutePath();
    ArrayList<String> noteFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String file : filesDir.list()) {
        if(file.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)) {
            noteFiles.add(file);
        }
    }

    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    for(int i = 0; i < noteFiles.size(); i++) {
        try{
            fis = context.openFileInput(noteFiles.get(i));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            notes.add((Notes)ois.readObject());

            fis.close();
            ois.close();



        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    return notes;

}

public static Notes getNoteByName(Context context, String fileName) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
    Notes notes;

    if(file.exists()) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        try {
            fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            notes = (Notes) ois.readObject();

            fis.close();
            ois.close();

        } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return notes;
    }

    return null;
}

public static void deleteNote(Context context, String fileName) {
    File Dir = context.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(Dir, fileName);

    if (file.exists()) file.delete();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it has nothing to do directly with `FileInputStream`. You happen to be writing to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). The only things with access to those files are your app and rooted device users. If you were writing elsewhere — such as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) — more apps might have access to it.

Comment: would this be a form of security in terms of data protection, i know its not quite as strong as encryption however does it make it more difficult to access the data for a hacker?

Comment: @Jay1: That would depend entirely on what you mean by "hacker". It goes a long way towards preventing malware from accessing the file. It does not help much if somebody steals the phone, though, as they can elect to try to root it.

Comment: so it prevents malware from accessing the file? the only reason i ask is because this is a uni project where i have to create a security app but do not have time to implement encryption due to lack of knowledge and understanding so as long as the data is secure from virus/malware attacks that would fine i think

Comment: @Jay1: "so it prevents malware from accessing the file?" -- it means that the malware needs to exploit some security flaw in Android to access the file. Think of using internal storage as having a house with locked doors. While burglars could break into the house and steal things, it is still more secure than if you did not have locks on the doors, or you had your things outside of the house. "do not have time to implement encryption" -- perhaps you should consider taking this up with your instructor.